# Displaying logo in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been trying to display an image in my JSP file but can't seem to it right. The picture is inside a folder named *"img"* which is in the same directory as my *WEB-INF* folder.

Inside my JSP I am trying to show the logo using normal HTML way of finding image but I can't seem to get it right. This is what I have for trying to display it. What I don't get it is when I am in Dreamweaver I see the image displayed but after deploying I no longer there.
I have a structure like servlet (which is root folder and name of my WAR file) and the *img* and *WEB-INF* folder are under it.

```
Folders follow the hierarchy below:

servlet 
---->img
     --->psyberAssess.png
---->WEB-INF
```

This is the code from JSP that is not working:

```
<img src="img/psyberAssess.png" width="450" height="100" border="0" /><br>
```

Comment: Add context path to your image url.

Comment: Hi KarthiKeyan, thanks for your response, so if I do get you correct what you mean is I should have a path of this sort ${servlet.contextPath}/img/psyberAssess.png where servlet is the name of my war file ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried using a jsp scriptlet like the following but still the pic won't appear <img src= "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/psyberAssess.png" width="450" height="100" border="0" alt="PsybersgateLogo" />

Comment: Hi @Raymond Nakampe I checked the `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/psyberAssess.png` it is working for me. Please clear the cache of your browser and check.

Comment: For some odd reason it continues to not display for mine when I use that even after clearing the cache. Out of interest how did you structure your folders ? i.e in which location did you place your img file ?

Comment: Hi I uploaded my sample in [github](https://github.com/seenukarthi/testweb) clone and run it using `mvn tomcat:run`

Answer (score 1):

just add the img folder in WEB-INF folder instead of other folder.

Answer (score 0):

Images and other resources must be outside the *WEB-INF* folder, they should be organized in folders in the root path of your web application. This is because the *WEB-INF* folder and its contents can be accessed only from the application server.

In short, your project should have this structure (the names are just a reference, you can name it as you want/prefer)

```
Project Name
- webapp
  - resources
    - images
    - js
    - css
  - WEB-INF
    - lib (libraries used on the project go here ALWAYS)
```

Comment: Hi Luiggi, Thanks for your response, I don't have it in the WEB-INF folder but they are in the root folder with WEB-INF i.e I have a structure like servlet(which is root folder and name of my war file) and the img and WEB-INF folder are under it.

Comment: @RaymondNakampe please edit your question and add the relevant content there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with JSTL tag:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/img/psyberAssess.png"/>" width="450" height="100" border="0" />
```